# Netrw problem - 'mt' open new tab instead of marking as target folder

Tags: netrw, filesystem

I was playing with netrw and was amazed by the possibility.

I'd like to mark some files with 'mf' and move it to a folder using 'mt'. However, when I press 't', vim seems to interprets it as "open a tab', because it open another instance of netrw in a splitted window. How can I do to mark it as target ?

My problem seems to be with the "t" shortcut in NETRW

```
t   Enter the file/directory under the cursor in a new tab|netrw-t|
```

Thanks for your help !

**Vim version : 8.1**

**Plugins** :

```
 2: /usr/share/vim/vim81/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vim/ftdetect/solidity.vim
  8: ~/.vim/ftdetect/typescript.vim
  9: ~/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim
 23: ~/.vim/.netrwhist
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim81/scripts.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/netrw.vim
```

Here my .vimrc :
set splitright

```
" NETRW
" open file explorer at startup
autocmd VimEnter * Vexplore .

" Resize file explorer
autocmd VimEnter * vertical resize 50
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w

" NETRW : set view type as TREE
let g:netrw_liststyle=3

" Disable header : I
let g:netrw_banner=0

" Open file in previous split
let g:netrw_browse_split=4

" hide vim swap files
let g:netrw_list_hide='.*\.swp$'

" To insert space characters whenever the tab key is pressed, set the 'expandtab' option: 
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

" fold indented text automatically at opening.
" to disable/toggle folding : zi
" za : toggle current indented block
setlocal foldmethod=indent
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

In netrw, :verbose map command return :

```
:verbose map t
n  t           *@:call <SNR>22_NetrwSplit(4)<CR>
        Modifié la dernière fois dans /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim

:verbose map mt
n  mt          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>22_NetrwMarkFileTgt(1)<CR>
        Modifié la dernière fois dans /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim
```

---

mf command is working great. I see difference when file is marked : Items marked become bold. I think this should be the same for 'mt'. However a tab is opened when I press 't' immediately after 'm'. Name of the folder doesn't become "bold" (marked).

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
:set showcmd
```

'm' is correctly displayed at the bottom of the screen.
'm' disappear just after pressing 't' key.

Below logs from debug mode (9) :
(translate from french)

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>22_NetrwMarkFileTgt[63]..<SNR>22_LocalBrowseRefresh[57]..<SNR>22_NetrwRefresh[16]..netrw#LocalBrowseCheck[23]..<SNR>22_NetrwBrowse[237]..<SNR>22_PerformListing[231]..<SNR>22_NetrwWideListing :
line   67 :
E31: No such mapping
Error detected while processing function <SNR>22_NetrwMarkFileTgt[63]..<SNR>22_LocalBrowseRefresh[57]..<SNR>22_NetrwRefresh[16]..netrw#LocalBrowseCheck[23]..<SNR>22_NetrwBrowse[237]..<SNR>22_PerformListing[231]..<SNR>22_NetrwWideListing :                            
line   70 :
E31: No such mapping
No such mapping: @$
```

Line 67 and 70 in function :

**/usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim**

```
NetrwWideListing
...
   if hasmapto("w","n")
    line 67 -> sil! nunmap <buffer> w
   endif
   if hasmapto("b","n")
    line 70 -> sil! nunmap <buffer> b
```

but I don't know if this is really the function that is the root cause of vim prefering to apply the other 't' shortcut.

if I do "nmap", I don't see "w" nor "b" mapping :

```
n  a           *@:<C-U>call <SNR>22_NetrwHide(1)<CR>
n  c           *@:<C-U>call <SNR>22_NetrwLcd(b:netrw_curdir)<CR>
n  d           *@:call <SNR>22_NetrwMakeDir("")<CR>
....
n  v           *@:call <SNR>22_NetrwSplit(5)<CR>
n  x           *@:<C-U>call netrw#BrowseX(<SNR>22_NetrwBrowseChgDir(1,<SNR>22_NetrwGetWord(),0),0)"<CR>
n  <F1>        *@:he netrw-quickhelp<CR>
```

strange...

---

**UPDATE 3**

I set up debug loglevel to 14.
It seems to be a bug.
When I press 't' just after 'm' ('mt' command to mark as target), a process/command SynSet seem to be launched in infinite loop (CPU fan begin to work harder). Log file contains same text in loop. Please find below link to pastebin that contain log file part that is repeated infinitely.
(Sorry but log are in french...)

https://pastebin.com/aKJyiTgg

Comment: Do a `:verbose map <buffer>` in netrw and see what you get

Comment: I suggest using `:set showcmd` so you can see the pending `m` and make sure it's there... The `mt` command simply marks the target directory, so the result might not be too noticeable unless you look at the top header... You need to use `mm` to move the selected files to the marked target directory (I guess you know about that... Just pointing it out.)

Comment: If you like Vim and like the idea of a file manager, take a look at ranger (https://github.com/ranger/ranger), it's very powerful and you can run it inside a Vim terminal (with `:term`.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble : It gives me :
n  t           *@:call <SNR>22_NetrwSplit(4)<CR>
        Modifié la dernière fois dans /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim
n  mt          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>22_NetrwMarkFileTgt(1)<CR>
        Modifié la dernière fois dans /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/netrw.vim

Comment: @filbranden :set showcmd command return nothing in netrw. I love vim, but I try to avoid plugins as much as possible (even if netrw is somehow a plugin, but is present by default)

Comment: @raoul59 Enabling `showcmd` will show pending keystrokes in normal mode commands, on the last line of the screen (below status line), so you can tell whether there's an `m` pending before you press `t`...

Comment: @filbranden I've had fun with `vifm`. Also, welcome fellow french-speaker @raoul59!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks! i'm french actually (in confinement, thanks covid19...). I updated description with some logs (debug mode).

Comment: @filbranden I tried vifm 2 years ago. Had fun with it :) my goal for now is to convert vim to a light IDE. Made some progress with covid19 confinement :) I updated description with logs

Comment: Very odd @raoul59 —E37 is only trigged when `unmap` commands don't have a mapping, but the only two unmaps are in lines 9629 and 9632 of `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim`, and they are `silent!`, so that shouldn't have caused the function to abort, nor should it have caused the regular `t` to fire.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks! Description updated.

Comment: Longterm, best bet might be to email the maintainer. He’s nice and prompt

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ok I'll do it and paste the answer here. Thanks guys!

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Interesting to note that I am using Ubuntu english version but with a french keyboard layout. I have not found the solution yet and I am quite frankly a little fed up with Netrw, going from bug to bug (another bug ongoing being directories shown as files)